# permissions in django with dispatch method

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to restrict users to view only the todos they have created using the dispatch method but i tried te below approach but still i'm seeing all todos appear under a user that did not create them

custom user model

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    profession = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
```

todo model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=320)
    to_be_done = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('todo_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

listview for todos

```
class TodoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Todo
    template_name = 'todo_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = self.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        for obj in objects:
            if obj.user != self.request.user:
                raise PermissionDenied
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

any ideas on how i can adjust to implement above said task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class TodoListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Todo

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Todo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

Comment: thanks man, any resources you could recommend to further understand using query sets in generic views apart from the docs

Comment: Read office Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#introduction-to-class-based-views) and also good documentation about Class Based View see [CCBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/)